# Why cvs2git not migrating properly when Attic folder in it?

Tags: cvs2git, cvsimport

I am trying to migrate cvs to git but the repository doesn't get migrated when the Attic folder in it. It's migrated README.txt file alone.

How to migrate properly even Attic folder in it?

**CVS:**

```
 ls -ltr /home/user/cvs/myproject/
total 4
-r--r-----. 1 cvs cvs 374 Aug 24  2015 README.txt,v
drwxr-x---. 2 cvs cvs  25 Aug 24  2015 Attic
drwxr-x---. 3 cvs cvs  20 Aug  8 12:39 resource
drwxr-x---. 3 cvs cvs  16 Aug  8 12:39 src
```

**After Migration:**

```
ls -ltr myproject-cvs2git/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 86 Aug 13 12:42 README.txt
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If it answered your question, you could accept it as the answer. The 'gamification' of getting points for correct answers is part of what drives SO. :-)

Comment: Yes @Mort. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Attic` subdirectories in `cvs` are  used for files that are not in the main trunk ('HEAD') or have previously been in HEAD but have been deleted.

There is no actual `Attic` subdirectory, you will find any files in `myproject/path/to/Attic/file` in `myproject-cvs2git/path/to/file` in the appropriate branch or previous version of HEAD.

You should find that these are correctly imported by `cvs2git` into the correct branch(es). If you examine a file in `Attic` and see what branches it is in, you should be able to check in git to see that it is there.